# How can i pick up a desease from the symptoms that it has linked to it in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

This is my first question on this page and sorry if I am not specific in some things or I do not explain myself completely well, moreover, English is not my mother tongue so I can make some grammatical mistakes so I'm sorry in advance.

Ok, I'm using a database in MySQL and I have a problem trying to get a query and return what I want, probably because my knowledge is not enough ...

Well, I have two tables, diseases and symptoms which have a many to many relationship, that is, a disease can have 1 or more symptoms and vice versa. This leads to generate another table that links the previous two and is this (the table is called diseases_diagnosis):

table diseases_diagnosis

Ok, now comes the problem, I want to take the id_enfermedade that corresponds to the exact symptoms that I pass (if it has one more or one less symptom it should not return that disease), I mean, I just one the system to return the disease which matches the exact symptoms that I introduce.
This is the real table that I got:

[image: name of the table: enfermedades_diagnosticos]

The thing is: if I pass the symptoms 2 and 6 it should return this:

[image: after passing id_sintoma 2 and 6]

BUT I want it just to return if the exact symptoms matches, i mean, if theres another disease with the same symptoms **plus** another one the system should ignore it for instance:

if we pass: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 it should return 6

but if we pass 1,2,3,4,5,6 it should return null or empty because theres no disease with those exact symptoms

As I have already mentioned above, my level of SQL is very low and prevents me from getting closer.

It's a bit frustrating when I can't cope with things of this level so I hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use `group by` and `having` like this:

```
SELECT id_enfermedade
FROM disease_diagnosis 
GROUP BY symptom_ID
HAVING SUM( symptom_ID IN (1, 2, 3) ) = 3 AND
       SUM( symptom_ID NOT IN (1, 2, 3) ) = 0;
```

Alternatively, you can express the `HAVING` as:

```
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(id_enfermedade ORDER BY id_enfermedade) = '1,2,3'
```

This makes it easier to pass in the list as a single parameter.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this seems to approach more to what I was looking for, I cannot test it right now, as soon as i get home I will let you know if this solved my problem. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: But I want to return a single disease according to the symptoms that I pass, so shoudn't it be like this?  \n 'SELECT id_enfermedade FROM disease_diagnosis... ' correct me if I'm wrong but your query would return a symptom, right? I am looking for a disease

Comment: @ÁlexP. . . . I appear to have gotten the column names backwards.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Okey, now its almost perfect, it returns the correct disease except in some cases, im gonna edit the images with the real table and data so you can check it better.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Okey I edited the post so now you can see the real table and data, sorry for not posting it since the begining but i couldn't.     Your code works if I pass 5,7 or 2,6 but when i pass 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 it returns empty for no reason, and in other cases too    this is what I do:     `SELECT id_enfermedade
FROM enfermedades_diagnosticos 
GROUP BY id_sintoma
HAVING SUM( id_sintoma IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ) = 7 AND
       SUM( id_sintoma NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ) = 0;`

Comment: @ÁlexP. . .. That is very strange.  I can't think of a reason why that would fail, unless "6" has another symptom further down in the list.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't know either, i checked over and over again and there are only 7 symptoms related to the disease number 6 u.u

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like this by looking at your table structure:

```
SELECT Top 1 id_enfermedade FROM disease_diagnosis WHERE id_sintoma IN (1, 2, 3);
```

It will return 'a'.

Comment: Okey, it's my bad there, I copy/pasted it and forgot to adapt to this question. My pasted code should be like this:   `SELECT id_sintoma` FROM disease_diagnosis WHERE id_enfermedade='a';  But what it meant is that i want the opposite result, for example something like this: SELECT id_enfermedade FROM disease_diagnosis WHERE id_sintoma=1 AND id_sintoma=2 AND id_sintoma=3;    and it should return a single row with 'a'. but it doest't

Comment: Now it is more like to what i was trying, but im at work right now and dont have it here, as soon as i get home I will answer  if it solved the problem thank you so much for helping ^^

Comment: While the result is technically correct, it will not solve the issue. 
Provided B, was listed before A in the table, B would be returned, not A.